# stored procedure returns varchar

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to know if in SQL is it possible to return a `varchar` value from a stored procedure, most of the examples I have seen the return value is an int.

Example within a procedure:

```
declare @ErrorMessage varchar(255)

if @TestFlag = 0
   set @ErrorMessage = 'Test'

return @ErrorMessage
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use out parameter or the resulset to return any data type.
Return values should always be integer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager
   @employeeID INT,
   @managerName VARCHAR OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @managerName = ManagerName
   FROM HumanResources.Employee 
   WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID
END
```

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx)

Comment: And to call: `DECLARE @ManagerNameOutput VARCHAR; EXEC GetImmediateManager 1, @ManagerNameOutput OUTPUT`

Answer (score 8):

You will need to create a stored function for that:

```
create function dbo.GetLookupValue(@value INT)
returns varchar(100)
as begin
  declare @result varchar(100)

  select
    @result = somefield
  from 
    yourtable
  where 
    ID = @value;

  return @result
end
```

You can then use this stored function like this:

```
select dbo.GetLookupValue(4)
```

Marc

Answer (score 5):

A stored procedure's return code is always integer, but you can have `OUTPUT` parameters that are any desired type -- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792.aspx .