# SQL call a SP from another SP

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures, set, declare

Can I please have some help with the syntax of a SP in SQL.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @Description VARCHAR(10)
)

AS

BEGIN
    return @ID + @Description
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    @LastName VARCHAR(50),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
    @Comment VARCHAR(max)
)

AS

BEGIN
    Declare @v_Value VARCHAR(15)
    Set @v_Value = usp_GetValue(@ID, @Description)

END
```

In the usp_InsertValue SP, I am wanting to declare and set a variable. Once the variable has been declared, I then wish to call another SP with parameters to set the value of the declared variable.

I am not sure of the syntax. May I please have some help?

**UPDATE**

I have updated my above code using your function. How do I Set the @v_Value from the usp_GetValue function.

I am getting this error:

> 'usp_GetValue' is not a recognized built-in function name.

**UPDATE2**

Here is my full code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_PersonCategoryLookupTesting
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
    @res  VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
)

AS

BEGIN
    return @ID + @Description
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertPersonTesting
(
    @IDTest VARCHAR(10),
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    @LastName VARCHAR(50),
    @AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
    @AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50),
    @AddressLine3 VARCHAR(50),
    @MobilePhone VARCHAR(20),
    @HomePhone VARCHAR(20),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
    @Comment VARCHAR(max)
)

AS

BEGIN
    Declare @PersonCategory VARCHAR(15)
    EXEC usp_PersonCategoryLookupTest @ID, @Description, @PersonCategory
    INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, MobilePhone, HomePhone, DateModified, PersonCategory, Comment)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @AddressLine3, @MobilePhone, @HomePhone, GETDATE (), @PersonCategory, @Comment)
END
```

I am getting this error in my application that is calling the SQL code:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '123Client' to data type int.

I am using the values "123" and "Client" for @IDTest and @Description.

Comment: There is no accepted answer there. I am still confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a function like that, not stored procedure. Stored Procedures only return integer values.

For SP, you need to create out parameters to retrieve the values. For this scenario, it is better to create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION usp_GetValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN
    return @ID + @Description
END
```

Then call it:

```
SET @v_value = dbo.usp_GetValue('John','Doe')  --output: John Doe
```

If you insist you want a SP, which is not proper for this, there are 2 ways

1) An out parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
    @Result varchar(20) OUTPUT
)

AS

BEGIN
    SET @Result = @ID + @Description
END
```

Then call it:

```
    Declare @v_Value VARCHAR(15)
    Set @v_Value = EXEC usp_GetValue @ID,  @Description, @v_Value OUTPUT
```

2) Select from it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @Description VARCHAR(10)
)

AS

BEGIN
    SELECT @ID + @Description
END
```

Use it like this:

```
declare @tempresult as table(v_value as varchar(15))

INSERT INTO @tempresult
    EXEC usp_GetValue @ID,  @Description

Select Top 1 @v_value = v_value From @tempresult
```

My advise is use the function approach.

Comment: @ConchPoulsen Call your function like `SET @v_value = dbo.usp_GetValue('John','Doe') `. Also read my answer carefully

Answer (score 0):

I think output parameters should be the proper way:
See this post:
[stored procedure returns varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924455/stored-procedure-returns-varchar)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
    @res  VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
)

AS

BEGIN
    return @ID + @Description
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertValue
(
    @ID VARCHAR(10),
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    @LastName VARCHAR(50),
    @Description VARCHAR(10),
    @Comment VARCHAR(max)
)

AS

BEGIN
    Declare @v_Value VARCHAR(15)
    EXEC usp_GetValue @ID, @Description, @v_Value
    -- use @v_Value here...

END
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '123Client' to data type int.