# Make Stored Procedure return a VarChar

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

First of all I am new to SQL, yet I have a great Java background. My problem is that I am trying to make this procedure return a `varchar`, yet it is not letting me.

I tried using the `RETURN` statement (I now know it only returns INTS) and the `SELECT` statement, but for some reason it continues to return an int.

Here is my code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE get_TopGuildLeader
AS
    --Variables
    DECLARE @LeaderUID VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE @GuildID INT
    DECLARE @MaxPoints INT

    --Selecting Leader
    SET @MaxPoints = (SELECT MAX(GuildPoint) 
                      FROM PS_GameData.dbo._GuildRankPoint)
    SET @GuildID = (SELECT GuildID 
                    FROM PS_GameData.dbo._GuildRankPoint 
                    WHERE GuildPoint = @MaxPoints);
    SET @LeaderUID = (SELECT MasterName 
                      FROM PS_GameData.dbo._GuildsBack 
                      WHERE GuildID = @GuildID);

    --Return Leader Name
    SELECT @LeaderUID;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stored procedure returns varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924455/stored-procedure-returns-varchar)

Comment: This looks like it could be simplified to something like `SELECT MasterName FROM PS_GameData.dbo._GuildsBack GB JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 GuildID, GuildPoint FROM PS_GameData.dbo._GuildRankPoint ORDER BY GuildPoint DESC) GP ON GP.GuildID = GB.GuildID` or something like that.

Comment: You **cannot** use the `RETURN` in a stored procedure to return a `varchar` - that's just not possible. So you need to use the `SELECT` as you are - so this really becomes a question of how are you **calling** this stored procedure and how are you dealing with the result set being returned?

Comment: @marc_s You can use `RETURN` to return a VARCHAR in a stored procedure. e.g. `CREATE PROC X @i VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT AS BEGIN SELECT @i = 'Hello World'; END` then `DECLARE @j VARCHAR(255); EXEC X @j OUTPUT; SELECT @j;`.

Comment: @ZLK: that is ***NOT*** using `RETURN` to return the `varchar` value! You're selecting it into an `OUTPUT` parameter. You cannot do a `RETURN @i;` in your stored procedure

Comment: @marc_s Oh, right. I don't even know what I was thinking when I read that the first time but yes, you're right.

Comment: you can use output parameters but it's a lot trickier to use.  if this is all you're doing, make it become a function instead, this way you can use it in queries and such....

Answer (score 0):

You need to return data using `OUTPUT parameters` instead of `SELECT`.
Refer link on how to achieve this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `output` parameter. However, be careful with your SQL query. I'm not familiar with your data model, but it looks like your query could result in a run time error. For example, is it possible that there could be more than one `GuildID` with the same number of `GuildPoints`? If so, the second query in your stored procedure will fail and return a message like below.

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

There are many ways to approach and protect against that potential issue. Below is an example of how to consolidate the logic down to one compact query and guarantee that there will always be one row returned.

```
create proc dbo.GetTopGuildLeader
    @LeaderId varchar(20) output
as
    set @LeaderId = (
        select top 1 gb.MasterName 
        from PS_GameData.dbo._GuildRankPoint grp
        join PS_GameData.dbo._GuildsBack gb
            on grp.GuildID = gb.GuildID
        order by GuildPoint);
go
```

Hope this helps.